# How to use nginx error_page to other location without replace url?

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy

This is a part in my nginx.conf.

```
     server {
         listen 80;
         server_name here.org;

         location / {
             proxy_intercept_errors on;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:2318/;
         }
         error_page 502 http://there.org/502;
     }
```

Now if i connect here.org and get 502,i'll be redirect to there.org.
But i want the title bar stay here.org instead of there.org.
How can i do?

Comment: You'll have to use proxy pass. Is it really what you want to?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I'm not sure. I want to redirect it to another page when 502 happen.Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Commented this line and your server will be return 502 error. if you need not default page, you can make html page and return this page of url 
`http://here.org/502;` add location:

```
location /502 {
      index index.html index.htm;
      autoindex on;
      root  /var/www/502;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i use docker and npm to build that server. How to do that? I think this can not work on my situation.

Comment: I think in your project there is config files for nginx, and in him commented line `error_page 502 http://there.org/502;`. Then you get Default 502 error on your domain `here.org`